# How to connect Azure-key-vault with a AKS pod?

Tags: node.js, azure, kubernetes, azure-keyvault

I have nodeJs application with docker file deployed in AKS with HelmChart, and I have azure key vault with some keys in Azure Portal and I need to connect my running POD with that KeyVault.

Comment: Any update regarding this issue?

Comment: Actually i am looking for sample application where i will try above scenario
Thanks ...

Comment: Take a look at the quick start page in the documentation I published.

Answer (score 1):

I use [akv2k8s](https://akv2k8s.io/).

Akv2k8s contains two main components:

1. The akv2k8s Controller syncs Azure Key Vault objects to Kubernetes as native Secret's
2. The akv2k8s Injector injects Azure Key Vault objects as environment variables directly into your application.

Diagram:

[image]

**Before you start with the installation I suggest to read [How it works?](https://akv2k8s.io/how-it-works/) page.**

Later on, Follow [installation overview](https://akv2k8s.io/installation/) page in order to set up the environment.

In case you want to install akv2k8s with helm. I created this code snippet for my CI\CD process :

```sh
# Create a dedicated namespace for akv2k8s
kubectl create ns akv2k8s

# Add Helm repository
helm repo add spv-charts http://charts.spvapi.no
helm repo update

# Install the Controller (and the "AzureKeyVaultSecret" CRD)
helm install azure-key-vault-controller spv-charts/azure-key-vault-controller --namespace akv2k8s

# Install the Env-Injector
helm install azure-key-vault-env-injector spv-charts/azure-key-vault-env-injector --set installCrd=false --namespace akv2k8s
```

simple [example](https://akv2k8s.io/tutorials/sync/1-secret/):

```
cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: spv.no/v1alpha1
kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
metadata:
  name: secret-sync 
  namespace: $(K8S_NAMESPACE)
spec:
  vault:
    name: ${KEY_VAULT_NAME} # name of key vault
    object:
      name: $(KEY_VALUT_OBJECT_NAME)  # name of the akv object
      type: $(KEY_VALUT_TYPE) # akv object type
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to existing answer (and I think this existing answer is the way to go) would be using [AAD Pod Identity](https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity). Basically its a way for you to have an identity for the application inside the pod. This way you dont have to micromanage the identity and dont have to pass credentials to the application (just use the internal endpoint). Similarly to the managed identity in Azure outside of kubernetes.